# How to ignore "can't open file" error message in unix

Tags: shell, unix, cut

I am searching table name in all scripts across the directories in specific directory. 
eg. home/abcd

I have abc, pqr, xyz directory under home/abcd. I have my project specific scripts inside these directories.

I have used the command like this.

```
grep table_name home/abcd/abc | cut -d":" -f1 > output.txt
```

Here, whenever the file under this directory don't have READ permission, I am getting an error message like this:

> Can't open the file.

But, I don't want to show this message on the screen.

Comment: also there is a `-s` flag that suppresses such messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `2>/dev/null` so that stderr will not appear:

```
grep table_name home/abcd/abc 2>/dev/null | cut -d":" -f1 > output.txt
```

#### Test

```
$ ls -ltr a*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 24 Oct  9 14:06 a
--wx-wx-wx 1 me me  0 Oct  9 14:10 a1 <--- no reading rights
$ grep a a*
a:123 abc
grep: a1: Permission denied
$ 
$ grep a a* 2>/dev/null
a:123 abc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick and accurate response. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-s` option with `grep`.  The command will be

```
grep -s table_name home/abcd/abc | cut -d":" -f1 > output.txt
```

Comment: While this answer might precisely solve the OP's question. Still it is good to know that `man grep` says -s : 
_"'-s':
     Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
     Portability note: unlike GNU grep, traditional grep did not
     conform to POSIX.2, because traditional grep lacked a '-q'
     option and its '-s' option behaved like GNU grep's '-q'
     option.  Shell scripts intended to be portable to traditional
     grep should avoid both '-q' and '-s' and should redirect
     output to '/dev/null' instead. (-s is specified by POSIX .) "_